# YII2 How to send query result into jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, yii2

so I want to use jquery autocomplete in a textarea, the values I want to use come from a query (from 'RetornaTabelas' class in Yii2) in this class I got the method
getTableNames:

```
public function getTableNames($db) {

    $queryTemp = new Query;
    $queryTemp->select('con_name')
            ->from('MyTable');
    $tablesName = $queryTemp->All();
    $commandAux = $queryTemp->createCommand();
    $tablesName = $commandAux->queryAll();

    foreach ($tablesName as $tname) {

        $sql= "
        SELECT TABLE_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='".$tname."';
        ";

        $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
        $connection = Yii::$app->db;
        $command = $connection->createCommand($sql)->execute();
        $transaction->commit();

        return BaseJson::encode($command);
    }

}
```

My Javascript function:

```
$(function() {



    $.getJSON('HOW TO PUT THE DATA FROM MY CLASS HERE ?', function(data){
        var cliente = [];

    // Armazena na array capturando somente o nome do cliente
    $(data).each(function(key, value) {
        table.push(value);
    });

    // Chamo o Auto complete do JQuery ui setando o id do input, array com os dados e o mínimo de caracteres para disparar o AutoComplete
    $('.ace_text_input').autocomplete({ source: table, minLength: 3});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

1. in your controller/action, return your data as array. something like
   `return Post::find()->where(['slug'=>$slug])->asArray()->all();` or simply return a `\yii\helpers\Json::encode(...)` 'd object
2. call this url from your javascript with params. `<?= Url::to(['mycontroller/myaction']) ?>` is my way to get the url without hardcoding